# how to turn a DVI to tex?

Tags: latex, dvi-tex

Any idea how to take DVI files and turn them into tex?

Comment: something similar was today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620002/pdf-to-latex-linux

Comment: There is a related question about this in TeX.stackexhange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46779/10944

Answer (score 10):

This is similar to the problem of turning PDF into XML which is referred to as "trying to turn a hamburger back into a cow". Both TeX->DVI and XML->PDF lose information, both in the structure of the document and its semantics.

It requires a great deal of heuristics and a large corpus to recreate (some of) the original document. It is never usually 100%. The text strings may be possible, the vectors are harder. Bitmaps are almost impossible.

Comment: Oh, I really like the hamburger/cow picture! Very very descriptive.

Comment: @Boldewyn I got it from Mike Kay (Saxon) but he got it from somewhere else I thinnk

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is not possible. I think that (same as in PostScript) even recognizing words in a DVI files may require heuristics. A DVI file is a description of where to place individual letters on a piece of paper, and nothing more.

You can get partway there by either `dvi2tty`, or by running `dvips` followed by `ps2ascii`, whichever gives the best results.

Answer (score 4):

There's also [catdvi](http://catdvi.sourceforge.net/), dvitype, and dvi2tty, available from [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/).

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this is not possible. DVI contains informations about rendering the page and not which tex commands it has.

Comment: I think there should be no doubt that this is possible.  The issue is can it be done well enough to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

for whom ever finds this question again, or for all you who answered I found the best answer for me: 
what I was looking for is how indeed difficult, it's trying to figure out what could be an original tex that would compile to a given DVI (or pdf for that matter since i can turn the DVI into pdf easily). and InftyReader does it. it works prefect, i tried i a bunch of pdfs on it and then re-made them into pdfs and it was perfect!

Comment: Yes, good call!  OCR systems tend not be smart about linebreaks though: have you looked at how it handles multi-line equations.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Description of the DVI file format](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~asnowden/comp-cont/dvi.html) and write the programm. Result of your program will not be original text but it will be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Err, well, sort of.

The path of least resistance will involve, I think, a dvi->rtf convertor.  I've posted a question: [Q#1859373 dvi2rtf: who can convert DVI files to RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859373/dvi2rtf-who-can-convert-dvi-files-to-rtf-files).  And there I post an untested implementation, which gives a bad solution that throws away all formatting.

With such a thing, then you could use word2007/8 and the excellent docx2tex utility to turn the rtf to tex.

The results would be unpleasant to read, but I can see some use cases for doing such.